# XSL-FO: Multiple Pagenumber Sequences

Tags: xsl-fo

Have a document that has two sections, so need two pagenumber sequences, one for the document and one for each of the sections.

So each page will have the 2 page numbers printed

Section 1: Section Page #, Document Page #
Section 2: Section Page #, Document Page #

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is something like this:

- section 1 page 1, document page 1
- section 1 page 2, document page 2
- section 2 page 1, document page 3
- ...

**it cannot be achieved** using only standard FO elements and properties.

Each `fo:page-sequence` can either define a new `initial-page-number` or continue the previous page number sequence; in both cases, **each page has just a single page number**:

> The value of the **folio-number** trait on the first page returned by the fo:page-sequence is constrained to equal the value of the **initial-page-number** trait. The value of the **folio-number** trait on subsequent pages is constrained to be one greater than the value on the immediately preceding page.
>
> The **format**, **letter-value**, **grouping-separator**, **grouping-size**, **country**, and **language** traits are used to format the number into a string form, as specified in [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt). This formatted number is used by the fo:page-number flow object.
>
> <sub>[XSL-FO 1.1 recommendation, 6.4.13 fo:simple-page-master](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_simple-page-master)</sub>

Comment: Can there be a placeholder, lets say in the footer of the page, then register for a new page event, and keep updating the value of that placeholder, which is then printed on the page? I ask this question since you profile says, fop contributor, i am using fop, also i am ok with using non-standard means to achieve this.

Comment: To use "non-standard" means the solution is trivial. You process the whole document with repeating sequences which gives you the 1 of 1 of X, 2 of 1 of X to the intermediate format

Then you postprocess the intermediate format to inject the other numbers

Answer (score 2):

@lfurini is correct about XSL 1.1 properties.  However, if you are using AH Formatter, you can use `axf:physical-page-number` (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#axf.physical-page-number) on a second `fo:page-number` to get the physical page number as well.